# pairwise_distances with Cosine and weighting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-distance

Is there a way to get a weight into the

```
pairwise_distances(X, metric='cosine')
```

Potentially using `**kwrds`?

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
```

In the scipy cosine distance it's possible to add in an array for weights, but that doesn't give a pairwise matrix.

```
a = np.array([9,8,7,5,2,9])
b = np.array([9,8,7,5,2,2])
w = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1])

distance.cosine(a,b,w)
```

Where `w` is the weights.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `pairwise_distances` you can use the [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) method to compute the distances. This will use the [`distance.cosine`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) which supports weights for the values.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

X = np.array([[5, 4, 3], [4, 2, 1], [5, 6, 2]])
w = [1, 2, 3]

distances = pdist(X, metric='cosine', w=w)

# change the result to a square matrix
distances = squareform(distances)
```

Result:

```
array([[0.        , 0.05508882, 0.04898252],
       [0.05508882, 0.        , 0.07833123],
       [0.04898252, 0.07833123, 0.        ]])
```